# How can I use git log command with filename and option?

Tags: git

I want to retrieve only commit id of specific file by git log command

```
git log filename
```

it works. however

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" filename
```

it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: It works for me, what behavior do you have and what do you expect instead?

Comment: it works thanks to @Evert !!!!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `git log --help`, the synopsis section, try the following:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" -- filename
```

Interestingly, in my shell (zsh on macOS), I don't need the end-of-options marker (`--`). From the comments to the question, it appears this is the same for some other people.
So this may be a shell issue, or even a git version issue. Alternatively, you may have a case with a special file name, e.g. a name starting with a `-`.

Since the `--` marker is pretty safe to use, this can be very practical in many situations to use (not only for git), even if it's optional, just as a safeguard.